# How to transform input data inside custom component?

Tags: angular

For example, I have component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  inputs: ['data'],
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: '<p>{{transformedData}}</p>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  public transformedData: string;
  @Input() public data: string;

  // How to call this event on "data" change?
  public someEvent() {
    this.transformedData = this.data + '!';
  }
}
```

How to call `someEvent()` on `data` changes?

Comment: I wonder what is `moduleId` metadata?

Comment: @micronyks It is for relative Urls, more info: http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/

Comment: Thnaks for your share !

Comment: i'm using commonJs, my HTML/ts files are in app folder but compiled files i.r js files in another dist folder from where my app ran, now when i use `moduleId: module.id` it took path from 'dist/blabla...' but there angular2 found only .js files not HTML now how to tell angular to take path from src folder instead of dist folder ?

Comment: @Pardeep Jain, You can copy HTML files into `dist/blabla` too

Comment: yeah i can but this is not valid solution at all, is there any alternative to change the path while defining `moduleID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onchanges` will get fired when `data` is changed.So, within `onChanges` you can call `someEvent` function.

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  public transformedData: string;
  @Input() public data: string;

  ___________________________________________________________________________________________
  // EDIT: you can also do it. Not necessary but can be done this way too.
 //  Note: If you go with this approach, you don't need to use onchanges hook and don't require above @Input public data line.
    @Input() set data(data:string)
           console.log(data);
           this.someEvent();
   }
 ____________________________________________________________________________________________ 


  ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {

        console.log(args);
        this.someEvent();
  }

  // How to call this event on "data" change?
  public someEvent() {
    this.transformedData = this.data + '!';
  }
}
```